# How do I append one MutableLiveData List to Another in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, arraylist, mutablelivedata

I have two MutableLiveData Lists like so

```
  val products = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
  val moreProducts = MutableLiveData<List<Product>>()
```

Please how do I append 'moreProducts' to 'products' in Kotlin

Comment: What do you mean by "append"? If you mean "I want a combined list coming from each `LiveData`", either the consumer can do that or you would need a third `LiveData` representing the combined list.

Comment: @Francesc's solution worked for me, basically I just wanted a combined list from each. Still new to most of these concepts so I'm not sure what you mean by consumer

Comment: The solution you chose works for a point in time and will fail if either `MutableLiveData` lacks a value. If you are using `LiveData`, somewhere you should have an `Observer` that consumes the data as it becomes available. Depending on what you are doing with the data in the `Observer`, it may need to be the job of the `Observer` to combine your results.

Comment: Why you cannot use single livedata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
products.value = prducts.value.orEmpty() + moreProducts.value.orEmpty()
```